# why is slash / used in SAS tabulate procedure before options?

Tags: sas

I am learning SAS. I am a newbie on SAS.

Here is the sas proc tabulate procedure:

`proc tabulate data=dummyData;
var analysedVar
class classifiedVar;
table classifiedVar all, sum*(analysedVar) / box='some text';
run;`

What is the meaning of slash used at line number 4?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the documentation:

```
TABLE <<page-expression,> row-expression,>column-expression </ table-option(s)>;
```

The slash is specified before listing the options for the TABLE statement. It's how you specify valid syntax so it knows how to parse out the commands. A slash is commonly used to delineate options from general specifications in SAS.

http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/proc/61895/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a002473740.htm

Comment: Thanks Reeza. It is making some sense now!